# Could not simulate mouseEnter event using React Test Utils

Tags: reactjs

I was able to simulate click events using React test utils, but I couldn't  simulate mouseEnter events

I added sample component and it tests in jsfiddle to show this problem
http://jsfiddle.net/kirana/Uf4e2/2/

```
var Events = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            event: ''
        };
    },
    clickHandler: function () {
        this.setState({
            event: 'click'
        });
    },
    mouseEnterHandler: function () {
        this.setState({
            event: 'mouseenter'
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return React.DOM.div(null, React.DOM.button({
            ref: 'button',
            onClick: this.clickHandler,
            onMouseEnter: this.mouseEnterHandler
        }, 'click or mouseenter'), React.DOM.div(null, this.state.event));
    }
});


var ReactTestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

describe('Events', function () {
    it('should have click event state', function (done) {
        var events = Events();
        ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(events);
        ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(events.refs.button.getDOMNode());
        events.state.event.should.equal('click');
        done();
    });

    // This test is failing 
    it('should have mouseenter event state', function (done) {
        var events = Events();
        ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(events);
        ReactTestUtils.Simulate.mouseEnter(events.refs.button.getDOMNode());
        events.state.event.should.equal('mouseenter');
        done();
    });

});
```

I couldn't figure out what I am missing to simulate mouseEnter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently mouseenter/mouseleave can't be simulated directly using ReactTestUtils; see this open issue: [Simulate.mouseEnter and Simulate.mouseLeave not working](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1297).

As a workaround for now, you can use `SimulateNative.mouseOver` and `SimulateNative.mouseOut` (making sure to specify `relatedTarget` appropriately on each) and together they will cause React to fire onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a bit different now as the mouseOver event works in React since v0.11.1 - see [here](http://qiita.com/kimagure/items/cf5200b0a2a516ca68f8)

That means you can now use

```
ReactTestUtils.Simulate.mouseEnter(events.refs.button.getDOMNode());
```

just as you tried in your example.